# Why does "\ " sometimes expand to a single whitespace in Vim's 'statusline', sometimes not?

Tags: vim

In my 'statusline' I have `%{&ff}%{'\ '.&fenc}`. The `'\ '` does not expand to a space, but if I change it to `'\ \ '` it does. What's going on?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but why don't you just do `set statusline=%{&ff}\ %{&fenc}` or `let &statusline="%{&ff} %{&fenc}"`?

Comment: I was working on an expression that would omit the space after &ff if &fenc was empty (unwritten buffer or undetected fenc) and stumbled upon this behaviour that I didn't understand. It is mainly a curiousity question since I could do it in many other ways. I just copy pasted a simplified version of the behaviour.

Comment: (%{&ff}%{&fenc==''?'':'\ \ '.&fenc})Here's the original bit. It works, for some reason, because I use '\ \ ':

Comment: @Sarah Reported it to vim-dev mailing group. It will probably be fixed, so do not use your workaround, try `%{&ff}%{empty(&fenc)?'':'\ '}%{&fenc}` (it works if `%{}` group does not contain any non-space characters).

Comment: It also works if `%{}` group is not preceded by any other `%{}` group.

Comment: Thanks! It did seem rather counter-intuitive. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug: I reported it to vim-dev and that was [the answer from Bram Moolenaar](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/msg/1c7812c5f5401a61):

> ZyX wrote:
>
> > The following code will show `||' in a statusline while it is expected to
> >     show
> >
> > `| |':
> >         vim -u NONE -c 'set laststatus=2' -c 'let &statusline="%{\"|\"}%{\"
> >         |\"}"'
> >
> > None of the following code have this issue:
> >         vim -u NONE -c 'set laststatus=2' -c 'let &statusline="%{\"|\"}%{\"
> >         \"}|"' vim -u NONE -c 'set laststatus=2' -c 'let &statusline="|%{\"
> >         |\"}"' vim -u NONE -c 'set laststatus=2' -c 'let &statusline="|%{\"
> >         \"}|"'
> >
> > tested on vim-7.3.47 (revision df6b12c84b23).
> >
> > Bug found by Sarah (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067613).
>
> Isn't this just that leading white space from the expression is always
>   trimmeed?  No, putting another item before it makes the space appears.
>   Strange.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to report it and follow up. :)